# "Phone" is a required value on Guest Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, guest-checkout

I turned on "Checkout as Guest" and allowed one page checkout. I can't seem to get pass the 2nd tab "Billing" as it says "Phone" is a required field. Even after I add in a phone number, it says the same thing.

I have edited:

- /template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
- /template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
- /template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
- /local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

and have:

- removed the required class in the label field
- removed the php code for validation
- commented out the Zend_Validate lines for getTelephone
- updated the db per the link below:

https://swarminglabs.com/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout/

I have flushed magento cache and cache storage too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Write schema to update attribute telephone required to false:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
   $eavSetup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');

   $eavSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'telephone', 'is_required', 0);
```

Comment: Where do I add that? I don't really know much about Magento and I'm more of a front end person trying to work on this. Thank you!

Comment: The question is about Magento 1, the answer is Magento 2 code.